# how to make io_service post specific function every 200 seconds?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to do some operations such as checks every 200 seconds. How can I make the io_service variable to post this operational function every 200 seconds? Is there any library functions in boost?

Comment: Use `deadline_timer`. Call function from another function, call `io_service.post(function)` in this function, use `async_wait` with this function as handler on timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `deadline_timer` with an expiry time 200 seconds in the future, when the `async_wait` handler fires you can invoke whatever function you desire

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Timer {
public:
    explicit Timer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) :
        _timer( io_service )
    {
        this->wait();
    }

private:
    void wait()
    {
        _timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
        _timer.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code& error) {
            if (error) {
                std::cerr << "Could not wait: " << error << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            std::cout << "Done waiting!" << std::endl;
            this->wait();
        });
    }

private:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer _timer;
};

int
main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    Timer t{io_service};
    io_service.run();
}
```